# User Cancels App Update, Does Apple's ProfileManager Keep Trying?

Tags: ios, mdm

I've tried searching for this but surprisingly have not found much regarding how Apple's ProfileManager handles the app update process.

We have an Enterprise App that is pushed to a supervised iPad. When the app is closed, it will update by itself without user interaction. However, if the app is open, a popup will appear, asking to update now or to Cancel it.

If the user Cancels the update, will ProfileManager keep trying to update the app?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, if the user cancels the update, the MDM server should send the command again to trigger this process.